# vb.net DataGridView update label while typing

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, keypress, editing

I have a datagridview which I want to filter.

Above the datagridview I have a second single-row empty filter datagridview with the same number of columns.

When the user types in one of the cells I want to filter the main datagridview based on the populated cells of the filter datagridview.

Before applying the filter, I would like to update a label with the currentcell text while it is still being edited.

How do I obtain the text changed by the user before the edit ends?

Answer (score 0):

resolved - with c.EditedFormattedValue.ToString

```
Private Sub dgvFilter_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) _
    Handles dgvFilter.EditingControlShowing

    Dim tb As TextBox = TryCast(e.Control, TextBox)

    If (tb IsNot Nothing) Then
        RemoveHandler tb.KeyUp, AddressOf tb_KeyUp
        AddHandler tb.KeyUp, AddressOf tb_KeyUp

        'RemoveHandler tb.KeyDown, AddressOf tb_KeyDown
        'AddHandler tb.KeyDown, AddressOf tb_KeyDown
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub tb_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)

    Dim c As DataGridViewCell = dgvFilter.CurrentCell
    Dim s As String = c.EditedFormattedValue.ToString
    Dim totalFilter As String

    lblKeyCode.Text = e.KeyCode

    'If e.KeyCode <> Keys.Down Then

    cellName = dgvFilter.Columns(dgvFilter.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Name

    cellFilter = "[" & cellName & "] LIKE '" & s & "%'"

    'get the filter (other columns plus current column)
    totalFilter = FilterString(dgvFilter, cellFilter)
    Me.txtFilter.Text = totalFilter

    'apply the filter
    Me.lookupDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = totalFilter
    'Else
    'dgv.Focus()
    'End If

End Sub
```